# How to open an external web page from a Wicket modal dialog

Tags: wicket

I have a modal dialog in Wicket that contains a link. I need to open an external web page  (for example, http://www.google.com) by clicking on the link. The target of the link is set dynamically. How can I do this?

---

I think that my question hasn't been so clear(I apologize for that). I need to open Web page from modal dialog. Actually, I can explain the problem in the example of modal dialog that @Don Roby has proposed me (wicketstuff.org/wicket14/ajax/modal-window.0). If we click the "Show modal dialog with a page" link in the example, there will be shown the modal dialog with another link called "Open another modal dialog". By clicking on that link, I want to open Web page (for example: www.google.com). My question is: how to open a Web page in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PageCreator (instead of setContent()), and return a RedirectPage:

```
ModalWindow modal = new ModalWindow("modal");
modal.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator() {
    @Override
    public Page createPage() {
        return new RedirectPage("http://www.google.com");
    }
});
add(modal);
```

Comment: This isn't working for me in wicket 8 unfortunately. The window holds a blank page. (But RedirectPage does work outside of a ModalWindow). Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Is it a http page inside a https page? browsers block this due security issues (mixed content)

Comment: thanks for the response. It's actually a https page inside a http page

Comment: It seems this is also blocked by browsers. Probably there is an error message in the console describing the cause in more detail.

Comment: yeah exactly.. you're right. It says "Load denied by X-Frame-Options:... does not permit cross-origin framing". At least I know why it's not working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you mean.

I have found the solution here :

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/How-to-redirect-from-a-ModalWindow-td1889646.html

```
onClick( AjaxRequestTarget target ){ 
    target.appendJavascript( "Wicket.Window.unloadConfirmation = false;" ); 
    modal.show( target); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know how to deal with the modal, but there's an example of doing it [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/modal-window).  Opening an external link is not difficult, and there's an example of doing it [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/).

Answer (score -1):

how do you create your link ?

did you tried with an externalLink ?

new ExternalLink("applicationLink","http://www.google.com");